# translation invariance of Rotary Embedding

Tags: word-embedding, large-language-model, llama

RoPE (rotary position encoding), the positional encoding used in Llama, is a relative position encoding. The attention scores are bound to be decided by the **relative distance** between tokens only. Therefore, the position indices in the Llama model should have **shift invariance**.

But when I add all the position indices by a given number (e.g. 1000), the model's performance will actually be affected (which can be told from the performance difference on a downstream task). But why? Shouldn't it be **shift invariance**?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it should be shift invariant, but in practice it is very dependent on the numerical precision as it involves multiple nonlinear operations involving sines and cosines.

Lets look at a standard RoPE implementation in NumPy (unbatched for simplicity):

```py
sequence_length = 5

positions = np.arange(sequence_length)

# Construct some dummy query and key arrays of shape [S, H].
hidden_size = 4
q = np.arange(hidden_size)[None].repeat(sequence_length, axis=0)
k = np.arange(hidden_size)[None].repeat(sequence_length, axis=0)

frequencies = 1e4 ** (np.arange(0, hidden_size, 2.0) / hidden_size)
inputs = positions[:, None] / frequencies[None, :]
sin, cos = np.sin(inputs), np.cos(inputs)

q1, q2 = np.split(q, 2, axis=-1)
q_rot = np.concatenate([q1 * cos - q2 * sin, q1 * sin + q2 * cos], axis=-1)

k1, k2 = np.split(k, 2, axis=-1)
k_rot = np.concatenate([k1 * cos - k2 * sin, k1 * sin + k2 * cos], axis=-1)

np.einsum('td,Td->tT', q_rot, k_rot)

>>> array([[14.        , 12.16070923,  8.33341272],
          [12.16070923, 14.        , 12.16070923],
          [ 8.33341272, 12.16070923, 14.        ]])
```

The above code runs in double precision which is NumPy default and shifting positions (e.g. `positions = 100 + np.arange(sequence_length)`) gives the exact same result.

After reducing precision to float32, the differences are still negligible (within 1e-7), but going down to float16 the difference becomes relatively large (~1e-2).

Since large models such as LLaMA typically run with mixed precision, this would explain your observation.